# Not able to use docker run hello-world in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: docker

Not able to use docker run in Amazon Linux AMI

## docker run hello-world

docker:

> Error response from daemon: unable to find "pids" in controller set:
> unknown. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

## docker info

```
{ # docker info
Containers: 6
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version:
runc version: 
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.72-68.55.amzn1.x86_64
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.79GiB
Name: ip-172-31-0-234
ID: AGTD:BUGU:RDRN:CSHC:INSH:HCMG:QFYT:OUNC:NCVZ:UDAM:PJYS:3ZQM
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: magsgfin
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Amazon Linux is not supported distribution. There are't any official packages for that distro moreover, docker it is not tested on it.

It seems this error is raised by [cgroups package](https://github.com/docker/engine/blob/v18.06.1-ce/vendor/github.com/containerd/cgroups/paths.go#L60-L88)

You can try to run [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moby/moby/master/contrib/check-config.sh) to check if anything is missing or misconfigured.

Comment: I had already ran the script and might be important part has no file missing,

Comment: `warning: /proc/config.gz does not exist, searching other paths for kernel config ...
info: reading kernel config from /boot/config-4.14.72-68.55.amzn1.x86_64 ...

Generally Necessary:
- cgroup hierarchy: properly mounted [/cgroup]
- CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled`
- CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled

Comment: - CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED: enabled
- CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE: enabled

Comment: Optional Features:
- CONFIG_USER_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_SECCOMP: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: enabled
- CONFIG_LEGACY_VSYSCALL_EMULATE: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_DEV_THROTTLING: enabled
- CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_CFQ_GROUP_IOSCHED: **missing**
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF: enabled

Comment: Feilds with missing tag  - CONFIG_CFQ_GROUP_IOSCHED: missing
- CONFIG_EXT3_FS_XATTR: missing
@Raoslaw

Comment: @MamunArfin Give me some time, I will later on run Amazon AMI EC2 instance and try to run docker there